# Passing facebook info to HTML hidden input field

Tags: facebook, hidden-field

I have the below code in my .aspx page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="fbinfo" name="fbinfo" value="" runat="server" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="Scripts/all.js"></script>   

<script>
FB.init({ 
    appId: 'thisIsMyAppId', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true 
});

FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse); 

function handleSessionResponse(response) {
    if (!response.session) {
        clearDisplay();
        return;
    } 

    FB.api({
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, FROM user WHERE uid=' + FB.getSession().uid
        },

        function(response) { 
            var user = response[0]; 
            var userInfo = document.getElementById('fbinfo'); 
            $('#fbinfo').html('user id is:' + user.uid);
        }
    );
}
```

When I run it, VS IDE throws back an error message saying

> htmlfile: Unexpected call to method or property access.

And this highlighted this part of the code inside the *jquery.min.js*

```
{if(this.nodeType==1){this.appendChild(E)}
```

Question is how to pass a value from the fql queried to a HTML input hidden type control or asp:control (like Label or Hidden field) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#fbinfo` is an `input` element, as such, you cannot set `html()` inside it, but should instead, use `val()`.

Like this:

```
$('#fbinfo').val('user id is:' + user.uid);
```

For more information, have a look at the [val() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

Add Facebook namespace to HTML tag:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: spektom, I've already done that. It's not this issue actually, but thanks.